# Magento 2.1 mobile product page doesn't scroll

Tags: magento2, product-page

I'm having an issue with my magento 2.1 installation, basically when I go mobile, on the product page, I can't scroll down because of the product Image, I can just slide it, to scroll to bottom I need to take it from the very button, but I can't tell to do that to the users. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

here is a workaround for this bug which solves the problem from "Simpsonight",

at first **copy** `/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`

to your theme in **web** folder `/app/design/frontend/<package>/theme>/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`

and change function `onMove(e)` at Line 1418 with this code:

```
function onMove(e) {
            if ((e.touches && e.touches.length > 1)
                || (MS_POINTER && !e.isPrimary)
                || moveEventType !== e.type
                || !touchEnabledFLAG) {
                touchEnabledFLAG && onEnd();
                (options.onTouchEnd || noop)();
                return;
            }

            extendEvent(e);

            var xDiff = Math.abs(e._x - startEvent._x), // opt _x → _pageX
                yDiff = Math.abs(e._y - startEvent._y),
                xyDiff = xDiff - yDiff,
                xWin = (tail.go || tail.x || xyDiff >= 0) && !tail.noSwipe,
                yWin = xyDiff < 0;


            if (touchFLAG && !tail.checked) {
              if (touchEnabledFLAG = xWin) {
                stopEvent(e);
              }
            } else {
                stopEvent(e);
                (options.onMove || noop).call(el, e, {touch: touchFLAG});
            }

            if (!moved && Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff, 2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2)) > tolerance) {
                moved = true;
            }

            tail.checked = tail.checked || xWin || yWin;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in `lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`. Set "merge Javascript files","Enable javascript bundling" and "minify javascript files" to "No" In stores > configuration > advanced > developer

Of course flush all the caches after uploading the changed `fotorama.js`

```
             xWin = (tail.go || tail.x || xyDiff >= 0) && !tail.noSwipe,
             yWin = xyDiff < 0;

-            stopEvent(e);
-            (options.onMove || noop).call(el, e, {touch: touchFLAG});
+            if (touchFLAG && !tail.checked) {
+                if (touchEnabledFLAG = xWin) {
+                    stopEvent(e);
+                }
+            } else {
+                stopEvent(e);
+                (options.onMove || noop).call(el, e, {touch: touchFLAG});
+            }

         if (!moved && Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff, 2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2)) > tolerance) {
             moved = true;
```